# Drupal 6: Access CCK field in RSS row template of a View

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

I have a CCK field called "link" and want to add it's content to the -Tag in the RSS-Feed generated by Views 2. Is there any variable to access this information in the row template of a view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the Answer myself. By adding

```
$node = node_load($row->nid);
```

to your row template you have full access to the node and it's cck fields via the $node variable like in the node.tpl.php for instance.

Answer (score 0):

There is limited flexibility with views2 and rss feeds. Changing what is mapped to RSS fields is not easily done.

You can create your own RSS template which uses the fields as you would like. Look at theme information and you can see the templates to override.